# Sometimes when using Surround.vim I am asked to press ENTER to continue. Is there a way to bypass this?

Tags: vim

Example:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ol>
```

If I want to change this to an unordered list, I put my cursor on one of the `<ol>` tags, followed by the keystrokes `cst <ol <CR>`, after which Vim prompts to 'Press ENTER or type command to continue'. Usually I don't receive this prompt when working with surroundings occurring over one line, but always with those occurring over multiple lines. Pressing enter twice becomes quite a hassle over time. Is there any I could skip this prompt? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a need to press enter twice. Not even once! Use <kbd>></kbd> instead of pressing <kbd>return</kbd>

```
cst<ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it still requires me to press enter even after typing that. Any ideas?

Comment: This behavior is incorrect. 1) Make sure you have the latest version of surround. 2) disable other plugins 3) reduce customizations in your `~/.vimrc` 4) submit an issue to surrounds issue tracker

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I tried disabling everything in my vimrc apart from Vundle and Vim.Surround but I still had the issue for some reason. Fortunately, adding :set cmdheight=2 to my vimrc solved my problem!